# What are the essentials of a good PRD (product requirements document) for a new mechanical device

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, product-engineering

I need to write a non-technical product requirements document (PRD) for a new machine that I want designed.

I need to ensure that I have included all the salient information concisely and to the point.

I have searched online for template PRDs but all of the documents I have come across, assume that the product is software so do not fit the needs of a PRD for a mechanical device.

Can someone outline here, the structure and sections required for a PRD for a mechanical device (e.g. an engine), failing that, a link to such a document would suffice.

Comment: Cue hollow laughter: my favourite one is what *used to be* the standard PRD for the engines of military aircraft. "The engines will perform satisfactorily over the full operating range of the aircraft". That's it. All of it. If you asked for more detail, the answer was likely to be "Well, we don't know what the aircraft will be able to do till we have a prototype to start flight testing..."

Comment: see https://www.atlassian.com/agile/product-management/requirements

Comment: some background information of yourself would allow us to write a more appropriate approach to the question. e.g. Have you ever designed a mechanical product, have you ever read or written a requirement doc?

Comment: @GürkanÇetin I am a software architect by profession, ergo, I have written a few requirements docs (e.g. functional and technical). I have no hardware/mech. engineering background, so this is new territory for me in that regard.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli alright, so you're in fact familiar with requirements, tests, validation/verification. I'll try to 
sketch an answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we start, just a word of caution that an engine is not only a mechanical device, they come with their own controllers (FADECs), and most of the time they have to integrate with some software (even when they operate through a throttle servo).

Alright, I'll suggest two methodologies, both of them are applicable to many scenarios.

1. The Flexible Way
2. The Well-Specified Way

I've personally gone through both methodologies in aerospace and defense projects.

**Flexible way** can be used when you don't know the specifics of what you are doing,  e.g. you want to outsource the expertise of designing and integration of the subsystem. You can do this when you have good business partnerships with the subcontractor (who will develop and supply the Product). Several of the specifications of the design will eventually change during the project. Specifications may change because of the bigger system or because of the Product itself.

In Flexible way, the Work Description can be more important than the Technical Specifications (=PRD, as you call it). So it's two documents you have to consider:

1. Work Description: HOW will they develop the PRODUCT (including how
   will they interact with you)
2. Technical Specifications: WHAT will the PRODUCT do, or What
   properties will it have.

For the flexible way, writing a brief document will suffice. Key Performance Parameters, and Key Characteristics/Properties could be sufficient. So the structure of the document can be as follows:

1. General Specifications
2. Performance Requirements
3. SubPart-A Requirements (Assume that you know the main part breakdown of the Product)
4. SubPart-B Requirements
5. Interface/Integration Requirements
6. Other Requirements
7. Appendix (e.g. CAD data for interface, technical drawings, draft interface control document, etc.)

**The Well-Specified way** is used when the Product to be developed is so important that you cannot risk changing the specifications on the road. It can be a mission critical subsystem or a performance critical item. For sake of completeness I'll refer you to the Defense Acquisition template. [ref](http://acqnotes.com/acqnote/careerfields/system-requirements-document)

Structure of a System Technical Specification document is as follows:

- 1. Scope/Introduction    8
- 1.1. System or Subsystem Identification  8
- 1.2. System or Subsystem Overview    8
- 1.3. Document Overview   8
- 2. Applicable Documents    8
- 2.1. General 8
- 2.2. Government Documentation    9
- 2.2.1.   Government Specifications, Standards, and Handbooks 9
- 2.2.2.   Other Government Documents, Drawings, and Publications  9
- 2.3. Non-Government Publications 9
- 2.4. Order of Precedence 10
- 3. System or Subsystem Requirements    10
- 3.1. Required States and Modes   11
- 3.2. System of Subsystem Functional Requirements 11
- 3.2.1.   System or Subsystem Function    11
- 3.3. System External Interface Requirements  11
- 3.3.1.   Interface Identification and and Diagrams   11
- 3.3.2.   Project Unique Identifier of Interface  12
- 3.4. System Internal Interface Requirements  12
- 3.5. System Internal Data Requirements   12
- 3.6. Adaption Requirements   12
- 3.7. Safety Requirements 13
- 3.8. Security and Privacy Requirements   13
- 3.9. System Environmenet Requirements    13
- 3.10.    Computer Resource Requirements  13
- 3.10.1.  Computer Hardware Requirements  14
- 3.10.2.  Computer Hardware Resource Utilization Requirements 14
- 3.10.3.  Computer Software Requirements  14
- 3.10.4.  Computer Communications Requirements    14
- 3.11.    System Quality Factors  14
- 3.12.    Design and Construction Contraints  15
- 3.13.    Personnel-Related Requirements  15
- 3.14.    Training-Related Requirements   15
- 3.15.    Logistics-Related Requirements  15
- 3.16.    Other Requirements  16
- 3.17.    Packaging Requirements  16
- 3.18.    Statutory, Regulatory, and Certification Requirements   16
- 3.18.1.  Statutory Requirements  16
- 3.18.2.  Regulatory Requirements 16
- 3.18.3.  Certification Requirements  16
- 3.19.    Precedence and Criticality of Requirements  16
- 3.20.    Demilitarization and Disposal   17
- 4. Verification Provisions 17
- 4.1. Verification Methods    17
- 4.1.1.   Demonstration   17
- 4.1.2.   Test    17
- 4.1.3.   Analysis    17
- 4.2. Inspection  17
- 4.3. Special Verification Methods    17
- 5. Requirements Traceability   18
- 5.1. Traceability to Capability Document or System Specification 18
- 5.2. Traceability to Subsystems Requirements 18
- 6. Appendix    18
- 6.1. Appendix A: Acronyms and Definitions    18
- 6.2. Appendix B: Key Performance Parameters/Key system Attributes    18
- 6.3. Appendix C: Requirements Traceability Matrices  18
- 6.4. Appendix D: Verification Matrices   19

Comment: Fantastic answer, I'm glad you added the FADEC component, because yes, there is a software component that will run the engine and keep it at optimal performance. Regarding the subcomponents, I have already identified them - ideally, I would like them to be designed by different engineers (partly, because of IP issues) - **HOWEVER**, I don't know as yet, how I can define the interfaces between the sub components, since I have **NO** M.E design knowledge, If you could shed some light on how I could define the interfaces between the various components, your answer would contain EVERYTHING I need.

Comment: Assuming that the engine has the following parts: Fuel injection System, Turno Charger, Combustion chamber and pistons, assuming I have no M.E. designing skills, but have a "rough sketch" in my head (as a hardware inventor), where these things should roughly be (the idea is an improvement of an existing engine) - is there anyway I can break the engine down into its subcomponents/subsstems and assign a unique engineer per subsystem?

Comment: glad that the answer is useful somehow. :) You do not need to specify all intra-interfaces of the subcomponents, if you will outsource the complete engine system (FADEC, Engine and all other subcomponents (alternator/power distribution, fuel pumps, etc.))

Comment: but if you intend to break the engine down to several subcomponents and outsource them from different sources, than you'll have to define all interfaces inside the documents, or setup such a work-definition that they will obey you orchestrating the interfaces.

Comment: Btw, I would not try to play the engine self-integration role, it's a huge task and requires quite a bit of experience and know how. So, I'd go with "give me an engine, deliver this performance" route.

Comment: Finally, you can (and actually you should) share your draft SRD with potential supplier(s) to get their quotes and to refine the TechSpec.